# Angular two way binding between input and lists

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I have the following:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="title"></input>
<div class="list">
    <div *ngFor="let list of lists>
       <div (click)="updateNGModel();"> {{list.Name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is that let say there are 5 lists. When one of them is clicked, I would like to show the clicked value in the input field.

How do I create the two way binding between the value of lists and the input field value?

I am new to the angular and any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass in the `list` value to your `updateNGModel()` method, then within that method store the name (or whatever value) to the `title` property

```
// component.html
<div *ngFor="let list of lists>
    <div (click)="updateNGModel(list);"> {{list.Name}}</div>
</div>

// component.ts
updateNGModel(list){
    // store the Name value to the title property
    this.title = list.Name;
}
```

Now since `title` is 2 way data bound to your input, your input field will be updated.